# How to set an alert to only fire during certain hours

Tags: scom

We reboot our Windows print servers automatically twice a week.  Each time we do, we receive an alert per printer in SCOM 2012.

I've searched all over for a way to tell SCOM that I don't need an alert during non-business hours.  Is there a way to do so that anyone has come across?

I appreciate any pointers to a solution.

Thanks,
Robert

Answer (score 1):

You can write a script that can place the monitored objects in Maintenance Mode.  Best way to do this is to create either a dynamic or static group of the objects you do not want to alert on.  Then you can create a powershell script that runs prior to your reboot windows that places the group into maintenance mode for a duration that is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

In the Admin pane under Subscribers, there is a scheduling option for each subscriber.

Simply change the alert email to only be sent during working hours for that subscriber.